# Crystal reports asking for logon parameters after deployed to server from my local machine but one report is working fine without any issue

Tags: asp.net, oracle, deployment, crystal-reports

I have multiple reports to be displayed with crystal report viewer in aspx page. I wrote common code for displaying reports. To my surprise just one report is working fine and the other reports are asking for logon parameters for my oracle DB. This is happening only after deploying dev environment. All the reports are working fine in my local machine.

Crystal report run time versions are same in both server and my local box.
I have 32 bit oracle in my local machine where as the server has 64 bit.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Username and password hitting Oracle DB on Server should be valid credentials. i believe these credentials are valid on your local Oracle DB and mayn't  valid or doesn't exist on Oracle DB server. 
Make sure you have user details(logon) exists on Sever DB. That would fix the issue.

Comment: Server DB credentials are correct. I am using just one connection string through out the application. I am able to get data from server in all other parts of the application and also one report is working properly which  connects to DB to get data.